# Strange behavior of std::is_nothrow_destructible

Tags: c++, c++11, exception

The following code triggers `static_assert` even though I don't think it should:

```
#include <type_traits>

template< typename T >
struct Tmp
{
  ~Tmp() noexcept( std::is_nothrow_destructible< T >::value ) {}
};

struct Foo;

struct Bar
{
  // Comment this out for the problem to go away
  Tmp< Foo > xx;

  // ..or this
  Bar() {}
};

struct Foo {};

// This triggers
static_assert( std::is_nothrow_destructible< Foo >::value, "That's odd" );

int main()
{
}
```

When compiled with:

```
g++-4.9 -std=c++11 nothrow_destructible_bug.cc
```

The following happens:

```
nothrow_destructible_bug.cc:20:1: error: static assertion failed: That's odd
 static_assert( std::is_nothrow_destructible< Foo >::value, "That's odd" );
 ^
```

How come just using `Foo` to instantiate a template in an unrelated class make it lose its `noexcept` status? I thought this was a compiler bug, but I tried it with all recent versions of both gcc and clang and they all seem to give the same error.

Comment: Did you mean to check `is_nothrow_destructible< Bar >` instead of `is_nothrow_destructible< Foo >`?

Answer (score 4):

Where you use `Tmp< Foo > xx`, `Foo` is an incomplete type.  This violates one of the preconditions for use of `is_nothrow_destructible`, and its use is undefined behavior.  One possibility of that UB is for `is_nothrow_destructible` to be false.

Commenting out the use of Tmp will avoid that issue.  Since the template is not instantiated until it is used, commenting out the constructor will also avoid the problem because the template won't yet be instantiated.

Moving the definition of the `struct Foo` before `Bar` should also avoid the problem.

Comment: "is_nothrow_destructable [sic] will be false." It's simply UB. Anything can happen.

Comment: I wonder what are those conditions and where I could read about them? The fact that there's a silent UB in this case scares me

Comment: @dragonroot They're all in the language standard document.  If your documentation for is_nothrow_destructible doesn't mention that the type needs to be a complete type you should submit a defect report for it.